# Can i give a parameters on "cmd console?"

Tags: c++, cmd

I want to utilize CMD console.
For example
If a.cpp is like below

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        cout << "argv : " << argv[i] << endl;
    }

    string path = "c:\\test"; 
    
    vector<fs::path> v;
    vector<fs::path>::iterator it;

    for (auto& entry : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(path))
        v.push_back(entry.path());
    
    for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
```

and if I want to run a.exe by CMD console
it can be

```
C:\users> a.exe
```

and the result would be

```
"c:\\test\\test1"
"c:\\test\\test1\\test2"
"c:\\test\\test1\\test2\\lastdir"
"c:\\test\\test1\\test2\\lastdir2"
"c:\\test\\test1_1"
"c:\\test\\test1_1\\test1_txt.txt"
```

But What if I want to change path by CMD console

For example

```
C:\users> a.exe c:\\temp
```

and outputs will be

```
"c:\\temp\\temp_dir"
"c:\\temp\\temp_dir\\temp.txt" 
"c:\\temp\\temp_dir2"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this *portably* since C++17 using

```
#include <filesystem>
std::filesystem::current_path(std::filesystem::path(path));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I think i figure it out!!